# Roll a fair six-sided dice n times, find the probability of rolling both 1 and 2

Tags: probability, statistics

Roll a fair six-sided dice n times, find the probability of rolling both 1 and 2. Get both ones and twos (other numbers may or may not appear)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hint: it might be easier to find the probability of not doing that first, then taking the complement.

Comment: Question is vague.  Probability of what?   (both 1 and 2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using combinatorial classes from *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet
and Sedgewick we get from first principles the class of admissible
sequences of rolls

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})
\times \textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})
\times \textsc{SET}_{\ge 0}(\mathcal{Z})
\times \textsc{SET}_{\ge 0}(\mathcal{Z})
\times \textsc{SET}_{\ge 0}(\mathcal{Z})
\times \textsc{SET}_{\ge 0}(\mathcal{Z})
.$$

This gives the exponential generating function

$$G(z) = (\exp(z)-1)^2 \exp(z)^4
= \exp(6z)-2\exp(5z)+\exp(4z).$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$n! [z^n] G(z) = 6^n - 2 \times 5^n + 4^n.$$

for a probability of

$$\frac{1}{6^n} (6^n - 2 \times 5^n + 4^n).$$

Interestingly enough this sequence even has an OEIS entry at  [OEIS
A245020](https://oeis.org/A245020) where an equivalent definition  is
given.

Comment: It seems here I answered a question that was missing context, which has now been accepted. Therefore I will vote to close.